# Trying to write JavaScript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I can't figure out exactly how to make this work. I am new to PHP by the way.

Here is what I current have (zerkms's solution), and it *still* isn't working for some strange reason:

here is a link to the page on the server:

http://tinyurl.com/kd3gynk

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<?php



$srcmsg = 'http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
//

var msr = "<?php echo $srcmsg; ?>";

window.onload = document.getElementsByTagName('img').src= msr;
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="#" alt="Picture of the world" height="42" width="42" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes. I used firebug. it doesn't say anything except the usual error which is : The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: if you are asking about CDATA, that is just what you can use to make sure that all data inside the CDATA will be ignored by XML parser. just a style choice really.

Comment: No, I'm asking about the opening tag `\<script ...`.

Comment: I already fixed that issue, take a look at my EDIT in my post.

Comment: I still am not able to get the image to appear on the screen, even after trying zerkms's solution posted below.

Comment: It is still there in your first code block. If that no longer applies, please delete it (I tend to discourage Edit/Edit/Update lines, since that's the purpose of the version control - just remove what no longer applies).

Comment: I removed the old part of the post

Comment: @user1066524 - In regards to your original question, you want to "Write out the javascript", right or is this to be an `executable` script, or just plain `text`? You will most likely have to use `htmlentities` for that. I have an example I can show you that works pretty good, it actually echoes out the javascript, just not 100% as per your layout, but very close.

Comment: @user1066524 I might not have understood your question. But do have a look at the code I came up with on `Pastebin.com` see if that's what you are looking for - http://pastebin.com/4T2D1RN2

Comment: I tried your code, but it just showed a bunch of the code on the screen. here is what my page looks like on the server right now: http://tinyurl.com/kd3gynk

Comment: @user1066524 The link you posted above is an `.htm` file and I had a look at the source and noticed `<?php ...` in there. I have a potentially very stupid question, but I'll ask it anyway; if you're trying to run some code within an `.htm` file, it's not going to work. I guess I really don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve. I'm sure had the file ended in `.php`, I'd of seen the image you're trying to show. What am I not getting?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do: I want to learn how to take PHP and perform some functions within PHP which will then be transferred to the src of an html element. This is just a demo on a smaller scale, but I wanted to see if it would work, and it isn't. I can't get the string variable from within php to be called from within javascript.

Comment: for example, in my PHP I plan on detecting an ip address which will then be appended to an src in an element. Of course, this is not what I have shown in my example here, but this is what I plan on doing in the future. right now I am trying to get this to work on  a smaller scale. e.g. using an image address from a string variable declared in php.

Comment: @user1066524 Then why not use something to the affect of `header("content-type: image/jpg"); $srcmsg = 'http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg'; echo file_get_contents($srcmsg);`? You might even have better luck using JSON instead of having to try and pry JS into PHP, which is (pardon the expression) literally asking for it. Remember, you can't have any HTML above PHP code, you'll get an `"headers already sent"` warning/error message.

Comment: if i used json, would I have to make some sort of a GET request from a php file?

Comment: @user1066524 Most probably. I don't have enough experience with JSON, but enough to say yes. I suggest you ask another question with what you mentioned to me earlier, outlining your actual plan. I'm sure you'll get a good response if it's well outlined.

Comment: I think that's what i'll do, thanks Fred and Halfer for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the PHP part.

This is not working purely because you are attempting to change an image that doesn't exist yet.

Either move your script to the end of the `<body>` (right before the `</body>` tag), or use `window.onload = function() { /* your code here */ }`, or implement some kind of deferring system.

Comment: I tried window.onload = function(){ document.getElementsByTagName('img').src= msr;}; and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That would be because `getElementsByTagName` returns elementS. Plural. It'd be better to put an ID on it and use `getElementById`, but if you can't do that then try `getElementsByTagName('img')[0]`.

Comment: this the error I get when I try this: TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0] is undefined

Comment: Did you combine it with one of the three solution I gave you in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried combining it with your solutions. Wouldn't you only use the [0] if it was a child element within the element?  I thought [0]  refers to the index of the first child in Javascript--this has no children. But thanks for your help Kolink.

Comment: The `[0]` refers to the first element in the collection (in this case - usually it's for arrays but it works for array-like objects too). `getElementsByTagName` returns such a collection, in which `[0]` is the first element with the given tag name.